# PayPal refund permissions for custom payee

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have the following flow -
A buyer makes a payment, I add a customer payee on the client, pass the orderId to the server and capture the transaction on the server.

Can I do a refund in this case?
using the following API I get "PERMISSION_DENIED"
https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/0NA021645B5069646/refund

description: "You do not have permission to access or perform operations on this resource."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have permission to refund payments from someone else's account.

They need to [grant the permission](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/admin/third-party/) to your API caller account.

Once granted, for that particular v2 refund call you'll need to construct and pass a PayPal-Auth-Assertion header, documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/reference/api-requests/#http-request-headers

Comment: This won't help me. no one will grant me these permissions for goodwill.
I need to do that automatically. like when I ask for scopes permissions.
Is there another way of getting these permissions?

Comment: You could have a connect with PayPal app or something like that to request the scopes, and have the app approved by PayPal. Each user still needs to go through the connect flow and grant you the permission, though. You can't refund money from people's accounts without permission.